# slide out span with close button for mobile

Tags: jquery, click, hide, show

i'm running a linkedin script which views some member profile info.
It's placed on the far right and on desktop it's visible if you hover over it.
On a mobile it needs to be clicked, because hover doesn't work! So i made an example with a closing button so user know how they can minimize it.

But i can't get the close button to hide when you clicked on it

This is my code

```
<div id="social">
<div id="block-wrapper">
    <div id="linked-close"></div>
    <div id="linked-block">
        <p>Btn</p>
        <span class="hidden">

        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

THE CSS:

```
#social{
position: fixed;
top: 80px;
right:0;
}

#block-wrapper #linked-block{
height: 70px;
width: 80px;
background-color: #0076B7;
color: #fff;
font-size: 32px;
text-align: center;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
}

#social #block-wrapper #linked-block span{
position: absolute;
-webkit-transition: 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
-ms-transition: 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
transition: 1s;
width: 364px;
height: 30px;
background-color: red;
}

#social #block-wrapper #linked-block span.hidden{
position: absolute;
-webkit-transition: 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
-ms-transition: 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
transition: 1s;
width: 364px;
height: 30px;
background-color: red;
right: -370px;
} 

#social #block-wrapper #linked-block span.show{
-webkit-transition: 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
-ms-transition: 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
transition: 1s;
right: 0;
}

#linked-close{
position: absolute;
top: -55px;
z-index: 999999;
right:314px;
width: 46px;
height: 46px;
background-color: black;
font-size: 40px;
display: none;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
 $('#block-wrapper').on('click', function(){
    $("#social #block-wrapper #linked-block span").toggleClass('show'),
    $("#linked-close").css("display", "block");
 });
 $('#linked-close').on('click', function(){
    $("#linked-close").css("display", "none");
 });   
});
```

Also made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqovtktr/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have 2 events both being triggered if you click on #link-close. That's because you have an event on your wrapper - a click on close triggers a click on #block-wrapper right after and therefor after you set display:none there will be an immediatly triggered display:block on your closing element.

You have two options:

If you want to keep the event on the wrapper you have to stop the propation like so:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#block-wrapper').on('click', function(e){
    $("#social #block-wrapper #linked-block span").toggleClass('show');
    $("#linked-close").css("display", "block");
  });
  $('#linked-close').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#social #block-wrapper #linked-block span").toggleClass('show');
    $("#linked-close").css("display", "none");
  });   
});
```

That could cause several problems depending on the rest of your code. Might work for your case tho..
[Fiddle stopping the Propagation](http://jsfiddle.net/xqovtktr/4/)

A better way would be to put the first click handler on the actual element you want to click. In your case its the `<p>Hoi</p>`

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#linked-block').find('p').on('click', function(e){
    $("#social #block-wrapper #linked-block span").toggleClass('show');
    $("#linked-close").css("display", "block");
  });
  $('#linked-close').on('click', function(){
    $("#social #block-wrapper #linked-block span").toggleClass('show');
    $("#linked-close").css("display", "none");
  });   
});
```

[Fiddle without stopping the propagation](http://jsfiddle.net/xqovtktr/5/)